# Android show ImageView resource image using animation

Tags: android, kotlin, android-animation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PcItH.gif)

I want this image to appear with Zoom In Fade In animation, but when I set it to my ImageView it shows at full size and alpha first, then it appears with animation.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<set
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <scale
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromXScale="1"
        android:fromYScale="1"
        android:pivotX="50%"
        android:pivotY="50%"
        android:toXScale="0"
        android:toYScale="0" />

    <alpha
        android:duration="200"
        android:fromAlpha="0"
        android:toAlpha="1" />
</set>
```

```
val zoomInFadeInAnim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.zoom_in_fade_in)
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cross)
imageView.startAnimation(zoomInFadeInAnim)
```

Please help!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: Im actually just guessing right now its what I would try to do first.  1. set the starting alpha,  2 set the starting image size, 3. set the image.  4. start the animation.  Good Luck

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can easily do it this way in the Kotlin programming language.

`setAlpha()` deprecated. You should use `alpha`.

https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin/apply.html

If you are using Kotlin, I recommend using `apply`. It increases the readability of the code and saves code duplication.

```kotlin
class YourActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    private lateinit var imageView: ImageView

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.yourActivityId)

        imageView = findViewById(R.id.yourImageViewId)

        imageView.apply {
            alpha = 0f
            scaleX = 0f
            scaleY = 0f
            setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cross)
            animate().setDuration(200)
                .alphaBy(0f).alpha(1f)
                .scaleX(0f).scaleY(0f)
                .scaleXBy(1f).scaleY(1f)
                .start()
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code:

```
imageView.setAlpha(0);
imageView.setScaleX(0);
imageView.setScaleY(0);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_cross)
imageView.animate().setDuration(200)
    .alphaBy(0).alpha(1)
    .scaleX(0).scaleY(0)
    .scaleXBy(1).scaleY(1)
    .start();
```